# How to open App Store on iPad when it is filtered?

Tags: ios-appstore, vpn, app-store-connect

App Store is currently filtered in Iran, next to many international websites.
My friend is now living there. There are Apps that she needs, including certain VPNs that are still working in current circumstances. But to install any app she has to open App Store. Why Apple is so exclusive like that. Is there any other way to install apps when App Store is filtered?

Comment: Many apps (VPN apps included) are available directly from the developers with no need to download via the Mac App Store. A quick internet search should turn up many directly downloadable alternatives, some of which are available directly **and** via the App Store.

Comment: They just direct to App Store. Could you perhaps mention some VPN apps that can be installed directly on iPad?

Comment: I just googled "VPN for iOS" and the whole first page is filled with direct download VPNs with one exception that points to the Apple app store

Comment: Direct? Are you sure? For me they all point to the App Store.